# PHP @mail returning false

Tags: php, email, mime

This code is not sending email, and I'm getting no errors to indicate why.  How is one supposed to troubleshoot this?

```
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $headers= "From: " . $this->fromAddress . "  <" . $this->fromName . ">\r\n";
    $headers.= "Reply-To: " . $this->fromAddress . " <" . $this->fromName . ">\r\n";
    if ($this->cc != "") { $headers .= "CC: ".$this->cc."\r\n"; }
    if ($this->bcc != "") { $headers .= "BCC: ".$this->bcc."\r\n"; }
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $headers .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= $this->body . "\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "--".$uid."--";

    $mail_sent = @mail($this->toAddress,$this->subject,'',$headers);

    if (!$mail_sent) {
        throw new Exception('Email failed to send');
    }
```

The result here is the Exception is thrown and nothing else.  So @mail is returning false.  Not much to go on ...

As an aside, the mail server is localhost (that does not require authentication) which sends email fine using similar code.

I have compared this code to the successful code and, although I'm obviously not seeing the critical piece, all of the differences seem to me to be unrelated to core email sending code.

The php mail log reads:

```
mail() on [C:\Users\Owner\PhpstormProjects\CRM\classes\CompanyName\Email.php:75]: To: lowens@companyname.com -- Headers: From: lowens@companyname.com  <lowens@companyname.com>  Reply-To: lowens@companyname.com <lowens@companyname.com>  MIME-Version: 1.0  Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="7feeadcdbd29ed703423feb85438c14b"    This is a multi-part message in MIME format.  --7feeadcdbd29ed703423feb85438c14b  Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit    asdfasdf    --7feeadcdbd29ed703423feb85438c14b--
```

Comment: [Do you know what `@` does](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)?

Comment: Remove the `@` so you can actually see a useful error message.

Comment: Thanks.  No I didn't know what the @ did.

Comment: Did you actually check that `$this->fromAddress` contains a valid email address? If not, you'll be open to mail header injection.

Comment: fromAddress is specified statically in one of my own calling methods.  No need to worry about injection.

Comment: Seems like php email questions are the kiss of downvotes.  The ones I checked previous to this one were all swamped with downvotes, too.

Comment: @LynnOwens A downvote typically means the question doesn't show any research effort. In this case, it's explicitly stated in the manual as well as the [symbol reference question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) here on SO.

Comment: Well I respect SO too much to get into an argument, but in fact I had researched mailing.  I was ignorant to the @ sign and I was somewhat curious about it, and i should have sated my curiosity about it.  Anyway, fact is I'm still not getting an error message even without the @.

Comment: Why do you send the message body within the headers and not in the third parameter?

Comment: I may expand the code to loop through file attachments as other sections of the multipart message.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Remove `@` and any error messages won't be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>.:TheJokerHack:.</title><body bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
<center>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Squada+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- no txt inicio -->
<script language="Javascript">
<!-- Begin
function disableselect(e){
return false
}
function reEnable(){
return true
}
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
if (window.sidebar){
document.onmousedown=disableselect
document.onclick=reEnable
}
// End -->
</script>
<!-- no txt fin -->
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
<STYLE type=text/css>BODY {
  SCROLLBAR-FACE-COLOR: #000000; SCROLLBAR-HIGHLIGHT-COLOR: #000000; SCROLLBAR-SHADOW-COLOR: #000000; SCROLLBAR-3DLIGHT-COLOR: #000000; SCROLLBAR-ARROW-COLOR: #ffffff; SCROLLBAR-TRACK-COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; SCROLLBAR-DARKSHADOW-COLOR: #000000
}
.Estilo10 {
  COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-FAMILY: Haettenschweiler
}
.Estilo8 {
  FONT-SIZE: 10px; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-FAMILY: Haettenschweiler
}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
/*
An object-oriented Typing Text script, to allow for multiple instances.
A script that causes any text inside any text element to be "typed out", one letter at a time. Note that any HTML tags will not be included in the typed output, to prevent them from causing problems. Tested in Firefox v1.5.0.1, Opera v8.52, Konqueror v3.5.1, and IE v6.
Browsers that do not support this script will simply see the text fully displayed from the start, including any HTML tags.

Functions defined:
  TypingText(element, [interval = 100,] [cursor = "",] [finishedCallback = function(){return}]):
    Create a new TypingText object around the given element.  Optionally
    specify a delay between characters of interval milliseconds.
    cursor allows users to specify some HTML to be appended to the end of
    the string whilst typing.  Optionally, can also be a function which
    accepts the current text as an argument.  This allows the user to
    create a "dynamic cursor" which changes depending on the latest character
    or the current length of the string.
    finishedCallback allows advanced scripters to supply a function
    to be executed on finishing.  The function must accept no arguments.

  TypingText.run():
    Run the effect.

  static TypingText.runAll():
    Run all TypingText-enabled objects on the page.
*/

TypingText = function(element, interval, cursor, finishedCallback) {
  if((typeof document.getElementById == "undefined") || (typeof element.innerHTML == "undefined")) {
    this.running = true;  // Never run.
    return;
  }
  this.element = element;
  this.finishedCallback = (finishedCallback ? finishedCallback : function() { return; });
  this.interval = (typeof interval == "undefined" ? 20 : interval);
  this.origText = this.element.innerHTML;
  this.unparsedOrigText = this.origText;
  this.cursor = (cursor ? cursor : "");
  this.currentText = "";
  this.currentChar = 0;
  this.element.typingText = this;
  if(this.element.id == "") this.element.id = "typingtext" + TypingText.currentIndex++;
  TypingText.all.push(this);
  this.running = false;
  this.inTag = false;
  this.tagBuffer = "";
  this.inHTMLEntity = false;
  this.HTMLEntityBuffer = "";
}
TypingText.all = new Array();
TypingText.currentIndex = 0;
TypingText.runAll = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < TypingText.all.length; i++) TypingText.all[i].run();
}
TypingText.prototype.run = function() {
 if(this.running) return;
 if(typeof this.origText == "undefined") {
   setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + this.element.id + "').typingText.run()", this.interval);  // We haven't finished loading yet.  Have patience.
   return;
 }
 if(this.currentText == "") this.element.innerHTML = "";
//  this.origText = this.origText.replace(/<([^<])*>/, "");     // Strip HTML from text.
  if(this.currentChar < this.origText.length) {
   if(this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar) == "<" && !this.inTag) {
     this.tagBuffer = "<";
     this.inTag = true;
     this.currentChar++;
     this.run();
     return;
   } else if(this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar) == ">" && this.inTag) {
     this.tagBuffer += ">";
      this.inTag = false;
      this.currentText += this.tagBuffer;
      this.currentChar++;
      this.run();
      return;
    } else if(this.inTag) {
      this.tagBuffer += this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar);
      this.currentChar++;
      this.run();
      return;
    } else if(this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar) == "&" && !this.inHTMLEntity) {
     this.HTMLEntityBuffer = "&";
      this.inHTMLEntity = true;
      this.currentChar++;
      this.run();
      return;
    } else if(this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar) == ";" && this.inHTMLEntity) {
     this.HTMLEntityBuffer += ";";
      this.inHTMLEntity = false;
      this.currentText += this.HTMLEntityBuffer;
      this.currentChar++;
      this.run();
      return;
    } else if(this.inHTMLEntity) {
      this.HTMLEntityBuffer += this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar);
      this.currentChar++;
      this.run();
      return;
    } else {
      this.currentText += this.origText.charAt(this.currentChar);
    }
    this.element.innerHTML = this.currentText;
    this.element.innerHTML += (this.currentChar < this.origText.length - 1 ? (typeof this.cursor == "function" ? this.cursor(this.currentText) : this.cursor) : "");
   this.currentChar++;
   setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + this.element.id + "').typingText.run()", this.interval);
 } else {
 this.currentText = "";
 this.currentChar = 0;
       this.running = false;
       this.finishedCallback();
 }
}
</script>
<style>
td{align: center; font-family: Bradley Hand ITC; font-size: 18pt; color: black}
a{align: center; font-family: Bradley Hand ITC; font-size: 12pt; color: red}


</style>
<!-- facebook inicio -->
<style>
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}
/*User Style: Cambie los siguientes estilos para modificar el aspecto de la Caja de color. Est&#65533;n ordenados y con pesta&#65533;as en una forma que representa la anidaci&#65533;n de el c&#65533;digo HTML generado.*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#000;opacity:0.5 !important;}
#colorbox{
box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
#cboxTopLeft{width:14px; height:14px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
#cboxTopCenter{height:14px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TcJGMnSfOCY/TxrtzzHDLVI/AAAAAAAAFWc/mdndgrisRuA/s1600/border.png) repeat-x top left;}
#cboxTopRight{width:14px; height:14px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) no-repeat -36px 0;}
#cboxBottomLeft{width:14px; height:43px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;}
#cboxBottomCenter{height:43px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TcJGMnSfOCY/TxrtzzHDLVI/AAAAAAAAFWc/mdndgrisRuA/s1600/border.png) repeat-x bottom left;}
#cboxBottomRight{width:14px; height:43px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) no-repeat -36px -32px;}
#cboxMiddleLeft{width:14px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) repeat-y -175px 0;}
#cboxMiddleRight{width:14px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) repeat-y -211px 0;}
#cboxContent{background:#fff; overflow:visible;}
#cboxLoadedContent{margin-bottom:5px;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-PPvu-446sn4/Txrt1QsGH1I/AAAAAAAAFWw/_jWYVoR1HX8/s1600/loading-background.png) no-repeat center center;}
#cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-31strss_1-E/Txrt1J6NThI/AAAAAAAAFWo/4P12CJPj924/s1600/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
#cboxTitle{position:absolute; bottom:-25px; left:0; text-align:center; width:100%; font-weight:bold; color:#7C7C7C;}
#cboxCurrent{position:absolute; bottom:-25px; left:58px; font-weight:bold; color:#7C7C7C;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{position:absolute; bottom:-29px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FiJ_Xz7txEg/Txrt0sy1TiI/AAAAAAAAFWk/Llzvkeyy_J8/s1600/controls.png) no-repeat 0px 0px; width:23px; height:23px; text-indent:-9999px;}
#cboxPrevious{left:0px; background-position: -51px -25px;}
#cboxPrevious.hover{background-position:-51px 0px;}
#cboxNext{left:27px; background-position:-75px -25px;}
#cboxNext.hover{background-position:-75px 0px;}
#cboxClose{right:0; background-position:-100px -25px;}
#cboxClose.hover{background-position:-100px 0px;}
.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-125px 0px; right:27px;}
.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow.hover{background-position:-150px 0px;}
.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-150px -25px; right:27px;}
.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow.hover{background-position:-125px 0px;}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Facebook Likebox popup para Blogger
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#subscribe {
font: 12px/1.2 Arial,Helvetica,san-serif; color:#666;
}
#subscribe a,
#subscribe a:hover,
#subscribe a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
}
.box-title {
color: #3B5998;
font-size: 20px !important;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 10px 0;
border:1px solid #ddd;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
border-radius:6px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #CCCCCC;
padding:10px;
line-height:25px; font-family:arial !important;
}
.box-tagline {
color: #999;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}
#subs-container {
padding: 35px 0 30px 0;
position: relative;
}
a:link, a:visited {
border:none;
}
.demo {
display:none;
}
</style>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://yourjavascript.com/11215013191/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
$.colorbox({width:"400px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
}
});
</script>
<!-- Aqu&#65533; contiene el c&#65533;digo de la llamada -->

<div style='display:none'>
<div id='subscribe' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
<h3 class="box-title">THE JOKER TEAM HACK!! LIKE.<center><p style="line-height:3px;" >?</p></center></h3>
<center>

<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/TheJokerTeamHack&amp;width=300&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=%23ffffff&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=258" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:258px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</center>
<p style=" float:right; margin-right:35px; font-size:9px;" >Powered By | <a style=" font-size:9px; color:#3B78CD; text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.aizumblog.com">Blog Gadgets</a> Via <a style=" font-size:9px; color:#3B78CD; text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.mybloggertricks.com">Blogger Widgets</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- facebook final -->
<!-- cancion inicio -->
<embed src="https://soundforecast.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/bangarang.mp3&amp;autoplay=1" height="0" width="0">
<!-- cancion final -->
<!-- img inicio -->
<style type="text/css">
#image{
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.p0wersurge.com/js/jquery-css-transform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.p0wersurge.com/js/rotate3Di.js"></script>
<center>
<img src='http://www.anonmgur.com/up/414edddcabdaa863b94532ff4ff077be.png' id='image'>
<script type="text/javascript">
var open = function(){
    $("#image").animate({height:200},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
    $("#image").animate({width:250},{ duration: 2000, queue: false });
}
var rotation = function (){
   $("#image").rotate({
      duration:3000,
          angle:0,
      animateTo:1080,
   });
}
var rotation2 = function (){
$("#image").rotate3Di(360, 1000);
setTimeout('rotation2()', 3500)
}
rotation();
open();
setTimeout('rotation2()', 4800)
</script>
<!-- img fin -->
<div id="example1">
<p id="example2">


<br>
<font size="7" face="orbitron" style="color: #000000; text-shadow: 0px 1px 7px GREEN" ;="">THE JOKER TEAM HACK</font>
<br>
<font size="6" face="orbitron" style="color: green; text-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #000000" ;="">esta pagina web tenia una vulnnerabilidad y fue aprovechada!<br>the joker hackers</font>
<br>
<center>
<font face="Lucida" color=blue size=5 color=white>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheJokerTeamHack?ref=hl" target="_blank">| HACKED BY COSMOS  |</a></spann>
<br><br>Saludos a Lulzsec México y Anonymous Mexico !!
<!-- cursor inicio -->
</style>
<style type="text/css">body {cursor:url("http://www.fbvideo.16mb.com/files/cur.cur"),default}
</style>

<!-- cursor fin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//Define first typing example:
new TypingText(document.getElementById("example1"));
//Define second typing example (use "slashing" cursor at the end):
new TypingText(document.getElementById("example2"), 50, function(i){
var ar = new Array("_"," ","_","_"); return " " + ar[i.length %
ar.length]; });
//Type out examples:
TypingText.runAll();
  </script>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>

<!--
var rows=1; // must be an odd number
var speed=10; // lower is faster
var reveal=10; // between 0 and 2 only. The higher, the faster the word appears
var effectalign="default" //enter "center" to center it.
</script>
</html>
```